# docker-compose : Unsupported config option for services service: 'web'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am going through the [*Getting Started with Docker Compose*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) page.

In Step 3, I made a `docker-compose.yml` file as described:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes: 
            - .:/code
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: redis
```

But when I run:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

I get following error:

> Unsupported config option for services service: 'web'

What am I doing wrong? I was not able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: It looks like your `docker-compose` is too old and doesn't support the version 2 config format.  What does `docker-compose --version` show?

Comment: This is what I see: docker-compose version: 1.3.3,
CPython version: 2.7.6,
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: in my case, the problem was an indentation problem which was caused because `docker-compose.yml` requires a proper indentation

Comment: In my case I was missing `version: "3"` in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Needed to update from the standard debian 1.21 docker-compose to the 1.29 and it started running. https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Since this is the first result on Googling "docker-compose Unsupported config option for services", I would like to add that the most common reason as of 2020 is missing of `version: "3"`.

Just add `version: "3"` to the start of your `docker-compose.yml`.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/):

> There are currently three versions of the Compose file format:
>
> 1. Version 1, the legacy format. This is specified by omitting a version key at the root of the YAML.
> 2. Version 2.x. This is specified with a version: '2' or version: '2.1', etc., entry at the root of the YAML.
> 3. Version 3.x, the latest and recommended version, designed to be cross-compatible between Compose and the Docker Engine’s swarm mode. This is specified with a version: '3' or version: '3.1', etc., entry at the root of the YAML.

Comment: While I think this is correct and adding version: "3" is probably the quickest way to move on, seems odd https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#compose-file lists version: as depracated / informative only.  I feel like I should be able to leave it out.

Comment: `A Compose implementation SHOULD NOT use this version to select an exact schema to validate the Compose file, but prefer the most recent schema at the time it has been designed.` ... is written in docs.docker.com ... that's just confusing, because the top level `version` DOES affect the docker-compose run.

Answer (score 68):

Support for the version 2 compose file format was introduced in docker-compose [version 1.6](https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/compose-1-6/), released around February of this year.

You're using 1.3.3, from July 2015.

You need to upgrade to a more recent version to use the version 2 format configuration files.

Answer (score 5):

Added **version: '3.1'** at the top of my docker-compose.yml file and it worked

Answer (score 3):

In my case i had used a wrong indentation. Recheck indentation of your `docker-compose` file to ensure it is correct

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend upgrading your docker-compose version, At the moment the safest way to upgrade docker-compose is by deleting it and reinstalling it.

```
rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Reinstall:

Update the apt package index, and install the latest version of Docker Compose:

```
 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

Alternatively, to install a specific version of Compose CLI plugin:

a. List the versions available in your repo:

```
apt-cache madison docker-compose-plugin
```

b. From the list obtained use the version string you can in the second column to specify the version you wish to install.
c. Install the selected version:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin=<VERSION_STRING>
```

where <VERSION_STRING> is, for example,2.3.3~ubuntu-focal.

And verify that Docker Compose is installed correctly by checking the version.

```
docker compose version
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Ubuntu I had to be sure to use `docker compose` (with a space) rather than `docker-compose` (with a dash). On OSX it didn't seem to matter.

Comment: This actually fixed it for me, what an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Check the indentation of your docker-compose file.

Try to open the file with Notepad++ (8.4.7 or a newer version). The whole file should show a green strip in the left. If it's orange or the green strip doesn't show for the entire file, it means the file is not valid an therefore not ready to go in your command line.

Hope it helps. It did in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that can cause this problem, try these fixes:

- The most common reason is a missing `version: "3"` from the start of your `docker-compose.yml`.
- On Ubuntu: try `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`
- Check the indentation of your `docker-compose.yml` file to ensure it is correct