# What does following error in docker-compose mean while building for Django?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Below is `docker-compose.yml` file

> docker-compose.yml

```
services:

 db:
  container_name: djangy-db
  image: postgres

 app:
  container_name: djangy-app
  build:
   context: ./
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
   - ./app:/app
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
  links:
   - db
```

and when I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I get the following error.

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'app'
```

Comment: That you use an option 'app' in your docker-compose.yml that isn't supported.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I understand, but what's that option? Can you check docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Try defining compose version.

Comment: @IvanStarostin compose file is here, and I've defined minimal options required

Comment: So try defining compose version in your compose file. https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Comment: possible duplicate, please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724948/docker-compose-unsupported-config-option-for-services-service-web

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker-compose : Unsupported config option for services service: 'web'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724948/docker-compose-unsupported-config-option-for-services-service-web)

Comment: @IvanStarostin I've stated version as 3 and now it's working, ty Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a version in the compose file, docker-compose will default to the version 1 syntax which defines the services at the top level. As a result, it is creating a service named "services" with options "db" and "app", neither of which are valid in the v1 compose file syntax. As the first line, include:

```
version: '2'
```

I'm not using the version 3 syntax because you are using build in your compose file, which doesn't work in swarm mode. Links are also being deprecated and you should switch to using docker networks (provided by default with version 2 and higher of the compose file). The resulting file will look like:

```
version: '2'
services:

 db:
  container_name: djangy-db
  image: postgres

 app:
  container_name: djangy-app
  build:
   context: ./
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
   - ./app:/app
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
```