# Need to up my docker file in ubuntu "docker-compose up -d"

Tags: docker, ubuntu

```
services:
    postgres:
        container_name: 'lh-postgres'
        image: 'postgres:13'
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    redis:
        container_name: 'lh-redis'
        image: 'redis:6'
    nginx:
        container_name: 'lh-nginx'
        build: ./nginx
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./src/lh-app:/var/www/html/app
            - ./src/lh-api:/var/www/html/api
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
    php-fpm:
        container_name: 'lh-php'
        image: docker.io/bitnami/php-fpm:8.0
        user: '1000:1000'
        build:
            context: ./php-fpm
            args:
                - PHP_ENV= development
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        volumes:
            - ./src/lh-app:/var/www/html/app
            - ./src/lh-api:/var/www/html/api
```

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>
> Unsupported config option for services: 'postgres'

getting this error

Comment: That sounds like the error that happens if you don't put a [`version:` line](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#versioning) in, so you have a Compose v1 file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some ENV vars.

This is our docker-compose.yml for Postgres

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: "no"
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "8002:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: verySecurePassword34058
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: myDatabase

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: our-network
```

Other parts of the application, (like Redis, the NodeJS App, etc) are in other docker-compose.yml files, But since they share the same network, they talk to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned version in docker-composer.yml

```
version: '2'
```

services:
postgres:
container_name: 'lh-postgres'
image: 'postgres:13'
environment:
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
redis:
container_name: 'lh-redis'
image: 'redis:6'

Answer (score 0):

You should include your `docker` and `docker-compose` version in the querstion to help us answer you.

It would also be wise to define the `version: 'x'` element at the top of your compose file.

You may be suffering from an old version of the cli, akin to this question:

[docker-compose : Unsupported config option for services service: 'web'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724948/docker-compose-unsupported-config-option-for-services-service-web)